# Get rgba value from 0xRRGGBBAA

Tags: javascript, math, bit

I know how to get values from 0xRRGGBB:

```js
const hex = 0xFF0000;
const r = hex >> 16 & 255; // 255
const g = hex >> 8 & 255; // 0
const b = hex & 255;
```

But I cant find a way to extract the same values + alpha from 0xRRGGBBAA.

Would be great.

Comment: you mean from `"0xRRGGBBAA"` as a string ?

Comment: Your example will only throw a syntax error. How does your script extract the values for `r`, `g` and `b` from `hex`? How would you have to adapt it to work with yet another byte? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @misterjojo, nope, I talk about a Number not a String, would be easy with a string. @andreas, just got a typo on `b`  const (I edited my q) but your comment was useless.
Same for @jameskpolk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just one shift of 8 bits and a mask more.

```
const hex = 0xFFAABBCC;
const r = hex >> 24 & 255;
const g = hex >> 16 & 255;
const b = hex >> 8 & 255;
const a = hex & 255;
```

Comment: I spent hours searching how to get rgba from 0xrrggbbaa and found no answer, I tried to use 1 more step as he did but I used 32 and not 24 assuming it was a pow2 but it wasnt working... Now I got a 24 hint and figured out how it works. Thanks to spent time behing disrespectfull.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that

```js
const hexCut = (v,n) => [...n].reduce((r,c,i,{length:z})=>
  { r[c] = v >>8*(--z-i) & 255; return r },{})

console.log( hexCut(0xFF0000,'rgb'))
console.log( hexCut(0xFF000001,'rgba'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: @Andreas the difference is the extra stuff (do you hate that ?)

Comment: According to JSBench this is ~89% slower than my solution (with my solution wrapped to return an object like yours).